# Is it worth taking a UK Xbox to the US?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

I may be moving to the US and I want to know if it is even reasonable to take my Xbox. I realise that there will need to be a power conversion, but that aside we have lots of kid's DVD's and Xbox games that I guess are all Region 2 and PAL.

- Can I plug my UK XBOX into a US TV and get a picture? (PAL / NTSC question)
- Will I be able to use the same power supply?
- Will my Xbox connect to US Xbox Live or will it try to get to the UK?
- Can I use Netflix on a UK Xbox in the US?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much all modern TV's (since about 15 years) have no problem between NTSC and PAL (US Citizen living in UK.. not had a problem for years) maybe on ultra low end TV's, but even then I wouldn't think so.

Also, almost ALL PSU's are now capable of taking 110 and 220v and auto switch. they should be labeled with their input voltage(s)

> Will my Xbox connect to US Xbox Live
>   or be tring to get UK?

Edit: Seems your gamertag region is [set in stone](http://www.xbox360forum.com/xbox-forum/threads/108353-Is-it-possible-to-Change-country-region-Xbox-360-live-PLEASE-!!-Long-Question):

It was changable once, but not anymore.

> Can I use Netflix on a UK Xbox in the US?

Unlikely, unless it can be de-regioned in a way that doesn't conflict with XBL(i.e. modding)  as modding usually breaks XBL. I assume it is region locked in software.

Comment: Sounds like they locked it down because of people trying to dodge licensing restrictions.  This might be something Microsoft support could do for you if you convinced them that you actually are moving.

Comment: do note however, that the uk has a different type of plug!

Comment: Netflix availablity is based on your Live Account's region. I live in the Netherlands and have a European 360. However, my Live acccount is based in the US (moved here in 2007 from America). Because of that, I get to pay for MSP in dollars rather than euro, and I also have the US dashboard, including Netflix/Last.fm. I cannot *use* them because there is IP region blocking I believe, but I do have access to them. So it isn't based on the console, at least as far as accessibility through the dashboard goes.